# Error while refreshing profile in XCode preference

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I tried to upload my app in itunesconnect, i am doing the following steps,

1. i set correct bundle-id
2. code signing identity - iOS Developer
3. provisioning profile - Automatic
4. in Xcode preference, while clicking on the iOS distribution under + button, i got the following error.

"Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate"
"If you have your signing identity on another Mac, you can import a developer profile. You can also revoke the current certificate and request one again."

Comment: "iOS Developer"?  Shouldn't that be the distribution cert?

Comment: iOS Distribution certificate is not showing in build settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Download **all** your certificates **and** profiles from the Apple Member Center and save then somewhere you can access them.
2. Double klick **all** of them, that should bring up Keychain as well as Xcode
3. In Xcode, open your project's build settings and set the Code Signing Identity under Developer to your developer certificate and the corresponding certificates to Distribution.
4. that should be it, check Xcode's preferences for the certificates and profiles to make sure they're correct and it works.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has good and complete [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html):

Step-by-step guidance for enrolling in an Apple Developer Program and building, testing, and submitting your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be an admin or agent to make a distributable build.

Comment: I am using admin account only. It shows distribution certificate is revoked